# How to install Linux on a dynamic disk without losing the disk configuration?

Tags: linux, installation, dynamic-disk

I have Windows 7 installed and a dynamic disk. I want to install Ubuntu but I have the following constraints:

1. I don't want to lose any data.
2. I don't want to lose my current Windows installation.
3. If I tried to make a system image it will be very large (about 40GB)

What are the available options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install Ubuntu inside Virtualbox:

- http://www.virtualbox.org/
- http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

[Or, maybe as a program?](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer)

To dualboot Windows 7 and Ubuntu, as Ubuntu will not run on a dynamic disc, you have to convert the disc back to a basic disc and carry on from there. These programs convert without the lost of data.

To convert dynamic disc to basic disc:

From SevenForum:

- [Option 4 - free (depending on)](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html)

  links to:

  http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html
- Easeus:

  - http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk.htm
  - http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm
- Convert with Aomei Partition:

  - http://www.dynamic-disk-converter.com/
  - http://www.dynamic-disk.com/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.html

After this, divide the partition for Ubuntu and:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/01/28/dual-booting-windows-7-and-ubuntu-10-10/

Naturally it would be best to read the warnings and backup, just in case.

Comment: Nope , I want to install it on my machine .

Comment: You could use Wubi to install it in a single bootable file. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation for more details.

Comment: Wubi still uses a file on the windows partition. It's recommended to create a dedicated partition for Ubuntu.