# Installing Kali alongside with Windows 7, Kali can not see partitions

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, kali-linux

I have a problem that is taking me a lot of time to solve, and still don't understand how I got such a problem and what the solution for it is.
The problem is that I shrink the D/ drive, to get 50G free space for Kali, 
I setup Kali on USB driver, start the installation everything is OK, 
then in the section of identifying the volume where Kali will be installed,
**I can't find the volume I created specially for Kali**:

[image: picture showing Kali installation section of selecting volume]

These are the volumes I have:

[image: picture shows the volumes i have]

Please help me I need to figure this out, I saw some solution about using commands but I didn't know how use them.

Comment: looks like you're trying to install linux to a [dynamic disk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Disks).  possible duplicate of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/335872/how-to-install-linux-on-a-dynamic-disk-without-losing-the-disk-configuration)?