# Linux installer won't recognize unallocated space

Tags: linux, partitioning, multi-boot, dualboot

I have a GPT disk with unallocated space(about 280GB) which I'd like to use to install a linux distro. This is a 1TB drive divided as follows:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VHdV.png)

I've also already set the disk to AHCI mode instead of optane with RAID, however during the linux installation it only detects the 1TB disk as a whole an not my unallocated space, what gives? I've created both a MBR and a GPT bootable USB and both have the same problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to install Linux on a dynamic disk without losing the disk configuration?](https://superuser.com/q/335872/432690) (note the answer there is quite old, it may or may not be fully accurate in 2022). While Linux [may be able to read data from a dynamic disk](https://askubuntu.com/q/869770/693277), IFAIK you cannot install Linux on it. I may be wrong and some clever way may exist. *If* it exists, I think it requires a clever Linux guru rather than a standard installer.

Comment: Please translate to english the text in your image.